# DAC R-2R Design

Tags: dac

I am trying to build my own DAC using an R-2R ladder. I want the output to range from -1 to 1V.

Option1: Connect the ladder circuit directly to my MCU I/O pins. The I/O pins vary from 0 to 3.3V. Then I can run it through an opamp with offset and gain corrections.

Option2: Design the circuit below and run it through an opamp with offset correction.

[image]

I understand R-2R circuits absolutely depend on the resistance matching. My concern with option1 is the resistance of the I/O pins especially if they vary with temperature.

However, option2 takes up a lot more space and parts.

Does input resistance affect the DAC that much? And if so, is there a way reduce its effect?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: If you plan to use discrete fets I would advise you study shoot through current and how to mitigate it.

Comment: The orientation of your MOSFETs are all messed up. At the very least, your low-side MOSFETs are all upside down. There could be more wrong depending on whether you are using electron flow or hole flow for the convention of your gate-source arrows.

Answer (score 2):

One problem with the direct approach is that the GND and Vcc levels of the outputs will vary slightly with other things the MCU may be driving because of wirebond and on-chip resistances. If your MCU is not sourcing or sinking any significant current, and if your Vcc is stable and low noise, it can work very well for appropriate values of resistors. You can buffer any outputs that may need to drive something else.

For only four or five bits of resolution, you probably don't care that much. The outputs of a modern MCU operated at 3.3V will likely behave something like 100 ohm resistors so if you use resistors in the 10-20K range you should be fine.

If you want to use external MOSFETs you should use a higher reference voltage so that the P-channel MOSFETs get enough drive to reliably be low Rds(on). The N-channel ones see 3.3V so they just have to be low Rds(on) with 3.3V Vgs.

If you do choose to use the external MOSFETs you'd be better off just using a CMOS buffer chip of some kind. For example, you could use a 74LVC595 with a slightly lower (reference) supply voltage such as 3V from an LDO series reference chip. It will actually work fine at 2.0V but the output resistances will be much higher than with a 3.0V supply.

Answer (score 1):

Most modern microcontrollers have I/O ports have an effective resistance that increases with current draw, but is quite low at sub-milliamp currents.  I don't think most of today's PICs are as beefy as those from the 1990s, but around 1995 I did a music box using an 8 bit R/2R DAC using 1K and 2K resistors which worked pretty well.  When using today's weaker I/O pins it might be better to use somewhat larger resistors (e.g. 10K and 20K) but if the supply rails are clean I don't see any need to get fancy with anything beyond that.

One nice feature of an R/2R RAC I don't often see exploited is that it's easy to design it to have two equally-weighted inputs for the LSB.  If one does that, connecting one of those to a PWM will make it easy to add combine the effective resolutions of the DAC and PWM (using even a 4-bit R/2R DAC along with an 6-bit PWM would yield a 10-bit output at a sample rate 4x that of an 8-bit PWM).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I get what you mean in the first Paragraph. 
However, I didn't quite understand your second paragraph. How can sending PWM to DAC work in terms of the data I want to transmit? If you have any resources I can look at, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @DigiJockforLife: Basically, the idea is that if you have 4-bit DAC and output a value of 5 and you PWM the extra input at 75%, then the average value output from the DAC will be 4.75/16.

Comment: Ahhh. Thats an interesting concept. I will look into it! Thank you for your help.